# Obtaining Windows printer share SMB settings (for tsclient/rdesktop on Linux)

Tags: windows, linux, samba, network-printer, terminal-services

At work, I have access to a "virtual" Windows server terminal, which I can access through my Ubuntu Linux via `tsclient` or `rdesktop`.

Additionally, there are printer shares on this network, which can be accessed from any Windows PC on the network (including the "virtual" terminals); lets say the address is `\\printshares.company.com`.

Now, I open `\\printshares.company.com` in the "virtual" terminal in `rdesktop` (*avoiding `tsclient` since it has a [Bug #94743 in tsclient (Ubuntu): “Terminal Server Client isn't able to copy to/from clipboard”](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tsclient/+bug/94743)*) - and I can see all printers fine..

However, when I'm on my Linux machine directly on the work network, I try and do something like:

```
$ ping printshares.company.com
PING printshares.company.com (192.168.0.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C64 bytes from 192.168.0.200: icmp_req=1 ttl=124 time=10.4 ms

--- printshares.company.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.450/10.450/10.450/0.000 ms


$ smbclient -L \\printshares.company.com -U MYUSERNAME
Enter MYUSERNAME's password: 
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

Although the server cannot be pinged - at least the `ping` command tells me `printshares.company.com` can resolve to an IP (*obviously, I replaced the real IP with a local one; but otherwise the ping response is left*); however, as it can be seen, I am getting `NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE`...

Now, there could be many things wrong here - all those Windows workgroups and such could be wrong etc..

Is it possible to retrieve the - let's call them "connection settings" - from the Windows terminal session, so I could replicate them under Linux when running `smbclient`?

(*Needless to say, the IT department running these Windows servers is quite irritated by people using Linux; and will offer no support to those kinds of "customers". Furthermore, if obtaining those settings requires some installation on the client session, won't help me much, since I don't have permissions to install anything on the Windows terminal session. Still, I'd like to know if there is any kind of solution for this*)...

Comment: Try enabling `client ntlmv2 auth` in `/etc/samba/smb.conf`.

Comment: Thanks for that @grawity - for that line, I get: "`params.c:Parameter() - Ignoring badly formed line in configuration file: client ntlmv2 auth`"; From [Samba and NTLMv2 Authentication](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/samba-and-ntlmv2-authentication-536973/) I got: "`client ntlmv2 auth = Yes`"  which seemingly did pass, but still getting "NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE".. I'm trying to run now `smbclient -d5 ...`, and from that debug dump log, only thing new I can see is "`SPNEGO login failed: Logon failure`"... which still doesn't tell me much... Thanks again - Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be worth trying with -W DOMAINNAME  as well.

Comment: Yippie - thank you @Col, that is awesome - FINALLY LISTING PRINT SHARES :) And for posterity, my full cmdline is now: `smbclient -L \\printshares.company.com -U MYUSERNAME -W mydept.company.com` ; and also this works too: `smbclient -L \\printshares.company.com -U MYUSERNAME@mydept.company.com -W mydept.company.com` .... Many, many thanks again - cheers! EDIT: this also includes suggesiont by @gravity in smb.conf; there also I have: "security=domain" too. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: `security` is a `smbd` server option and is ignored by `smbclient`.

Comment: Many thanks @grawity - I wasn't aware of that; cheers!

Comment: @sdaau That's no problem, I'm glad I could help.